# Filtering one array by values of another array without nested foreach

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a small algorithm for filtering array by values from another array:

```
const temp = [];
autocompleteItems.forEach(autocompleteItem => {
  this.cashDataSource.forEach(cashItem => {
    if (cashItem.material === autocompleteItem.title) {
      temp.push(cashItem);
    }
  })
});
this.cashDataSource = temp;

// This can't contains duplicate.
autocompleteItems = [
  {
    title: '1'
  },
  {
    title: '2'
  }
]

cashDataSource = [
  {
    material: '1'
  },
  {
    material: '1'
  }
  {
    material: '2'
  },
  {
    material: '2'
  }
]
```

That else solutions with standard javascript methods like a `map`, `reduce`, `filter` and etc. including `foreach` but not two. Which possible to realize the same behavior, maybe without temp variable?

Comment: Try it with `reduce()` yourself. Then when you run into issues post that attempt along with some sample data

Comment: I feel like some more context might be helpful-- what is in `autocompleteItem`?  What does the source data look like and what is the expected output supposed to look like?  Without this information I don't feel like I can provide you with a meaningful/helpful answer...

Comment: Update question. Why this aggression with a hit by my reputation this is a small mistake, not spam. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you are after is filtering the `cashDataSource` by the `autocompleteItems` you can do something like this:

```js
const autocompleteItems = [{ title: '1' }, { title: '2' }]
const cashDataSource = [{ material: '1' }, { material: '2' }, { material: '3' }, { material: '4' }] 

// get the values in an array e.g. ['1', '2']
const autoValues = autocompleteItems.reduce((r,c) => (r.push(c.title), r), [])
// filter `cashDataSource` against the autoValues
const r = cashDataSource.filter(y => autoValues.includes(y.material))

console.log(r)
```